# Form api custom validation function doesn't work

Tags: forms

I'm trying to reuse the login form in my own form. So far so good, everything is populated and shown properly. Now I want to use my validation functions to validate some data, so I tried to add them:

```
$userLogin = drupal_get_form('user_login');
array_unshift($userLogin['#validate'], 'MY_UBERLEAD_FUNC_validate');
$form['selfservice_ad_tabs']['tab_3']['login'] = $userLogin;
```

Printing the form shows that the function is in the proper place, but it was not invoked when expected.

I tried several other methods:

```
$userLogin['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'MY_UBERLEAD_FUNC_validate';
```

also removing all validation handlers and leaving just mine, but those didn't work either.

Can somebody point what i am doing wrong or explain how i can reuse existing form **into** my custom form using my validation functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you use `drupal_get_form()` you can't alter the form because the form will be already built, cached and all the processing done.

Try this instead.

```
$form_init = array();
$userLogin = user_login_block($form_init);

array_unshift($userLogin['#validate'], 'MY_UBERLEAD_FUNC_validate');
$form['selfservice_ad_tabs']['tab_3']['login'] = $userLogin;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! I completely forgot about the form caching.

I suppose i'll be building my own form for the registration functionality since it's a little more complicated than the login.